# pandas data frame: get maxima of a column after grouping by another coumn

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I try to get maximum of B for each of the A's. C and D are there, because my dataset is more than just the 2 columns I want to sort and get the maximas of.

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 20, 10, 20],
            'B': [1001, 1002, 2002, 2003, 3001, 2003, 1002, 2003],
            'C': numpy.random.randn(8),
            'D': numpy.random.randn(8)})
```

Something like this:

```
df[['A', 'B']].somepandas(magic)
```

The desired result is:

```
   B
A        
10 1002
20 2003
30 3001
```

But so far I only understand to get the maximum of each column without grouping:

```
df[['A', 'B']].max(axis=0)

A      30
B    3001
dtype: int64
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `groupby` the 'A' column, then select 'B' column and call `max()` on the column:

```
In [42]:

df.groupby('A')['B'].max()
Out[42]:
A
10    1002
20    2003
30    3001
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

You can perform multiple functions on separate columns at once, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation

Comment: I still do not get the trick about the multiple functions on separate columns. Could anyone post an exmple including maybe sum and/or count of column `'C'` in the above example. Also another link with a turorial would help. Thanks

Comment: Basically you can call `agg` on the groupby object and pass a dict with column names as the keys and the function to perform as the values: `df.groupby('A').agg({'C' : np.sum,'D' : max})` see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I understand how to perform standard functions on different columns. But what if I want to filter at first on `'B'` and then perform on only this filtered results a function. `df.groupby('A').agg({'B': max, 'C': numpy.count_nonzero})` doesn't do the trick, because it just looks at each column separatly. The expected result for C is `2 2 1` not `3 4 1`. Sorry and thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question if you did this: `df.groupby('A')['B']` then you explicitly select just column 'B' and then you can still apply your functions to this only

Comment: Sorry, I had to edit my question because I hit the "Add Comment" Button to fast

Comment: Sorry please post a new question with data and code and expected output, I don't understand how you get that result and it's preferable you post a new question rather comment on a different question like this

Comment: Understood! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546602/pandas-data-frame-how-to-filter-on-on-a-column-and-afterwards-build-count-and-s