# pandas data frame: How to filter on on a column and afterwards build count and sum of other columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Here is the problem: I have following data:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30],
                'B': [1001, 1002, 2002, 2003, 3001, 2003, 1002, 2003, 3005, 3005],
                'C': numpy.random.randn(10),
                'D': numpy.random.randn(10)})
```

With this applied:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': max, 'C': numpy.count_nonzero})
```

I get:

```
    C     B
A          
10  3  1002
20  4  2003
30  3  3005
```

But I want only the count of C when it is part of the maximum value of B (grouped by A). I learned in an earlier post, that grouping can be done like this - still no count of C:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].max()
```

This gives me the maximum of B for each A.

```
A
10    1002
20    2003
30    3005
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

I am missing the last step to get this result:

```
A    B      C
10   1002   2 # 2, because there are 2 rows of B = 1002 with A = 10
20   2003   3
30   3005   2
```

In my project I do not know the values of B beforehand, so I can not set up a filter upfront.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> df.groupby('A').apply(lambda g: pandas.Series({"MaxB": g.B.max(), "NumMax": (g.B==g.B.max()).sum()}))
    MaxB  NumMax
A               
10  1002       2
20  2003       3
30  3005       2
```

The operation `(g.B==g.B.max()).sum()` counts the number of rows in the group whose B column is equal to the max value of B.

This way of doing it calculates the group max twice per group, but computing the max is a pretty fast operation, so this won't cause much performance impact in practice.

Comment: Thanks. I never would have found this solution